# Does the Abysmal Armour break in werewolv.es?

Tags: werewolv.es

In werewolv.es, the joke-version of the protective Abyssal Armour is the Abys**mal** Armour - truly terrible because it offers no protection, but blocks the holder at night instead!  However, if someone is killed at night whilst holding the Armour, does it 'break' like normal armour items and disappear from the game, or is ownership transferred to the killer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows the same rules as other forms of armour do (aside from offering zero protection) and it breaks if the person holding it is attacked.